# jQuery multiple event handler

Tags: jquery

What does the keyup() at the end of it mean?

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();
```

Comment: Doesn't this create an infinite loop ?

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right. Prorgrammers always learn I guess lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks ***[@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)*** Sir.

The code bind a `keyup` event to all `inputs` already belong to DOM and immediately trigger it for those inputs.

Now,

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("p").text(value);
});
```

above code bind the `keyup` event to `input` and last `.keyup()` makes an initial trigger to `keyup`.

You can rewrite above code also as following:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
    })

$('input').keyup(); // or $('input').trigger('keyup');
```

---

### Does it create an Infinite loop?

**NO**, It triggers just one time at page load. See [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/506/)

Comment: Does it really do that after page load? Is it standard? TIL if ever. :)

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan yup it does, if the code wrapper within jQuery DOM ready function

Comment: Note that it doesn't necessarily have to be in a DOM ready function: http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/507/ It would be more accurate to say that the code binds a keyup handler to any input elements already in the DOM and immediately triggers a keyup event for those elements.

Comment: @thecodeparadox ooppss... Sorry, I forgot to. It told me to accept it in 10 minutes, but it looks like I procrastinated accepting it lol

Answer (score 1):

The first .keyup is a binding method the second one is a trigger method:

```
$("input")
    .keyup(function () { // Bind on keyup
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("p").text(value);
    })
    .keyup(); // Trigger keyup
```